# AWS Redshift Query optimization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am executing below query which runs against a database table having millions of records.

The user will upload data in a text file to a table. Using that data, I need to do a `like` match against a table (company_classification) which has millions of records.

It takes close to 16 minutes to complete the execution for an input file of size 1K. I also tried to JOIN explicit but again the same cost. Need suggestions on optimizing the query, so that it can get executed 2-3 minutes. This query is an triggered from a front-end polymer web page.

Below is the explain plan and also have attached `svl_query_summary` output.

Query:

```
select
  count(*)
from company_classification c
join dev.input_data_load d on (c.industry_cls_code like d.industry_code||'%')
where
      d.id = '51993d75f7cf2647647b58250222d954'
  and d.company_indicator = 1

----- Nested Loop Join in the query plan - review the join predicates to avoid Cartesian products -----
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question does not have enough detail to offer suggestions. Please EDIT your question and add information the SORTKEY and DISTKEY for each table. Your question also mentions an Explain Plan and `svl_query_summary` output but they are not shown in your question.

Comment: Are you using id as a DIST key?